# How do I emulate Dualshock 4 gyro on a Steam Deck?

Tags: controllers, steam-deck, deathloop

Some games like Deathloop and Fortnite have motion sensor aiming options that were designed for PS4 Dualshock controllers. Is there a way to emulate a PS4 controller on a Steam Deck to enable the gyro option?

[image: Deathloop Dualshock 4 gyro option]

I know Steam Input has other ways to map gyro controls, but each comes with drawbacks. Mapping gyro to a joystick often feels unnatural, an emulated keyboard and mouse setup removes gamepad button prompts, and the "Gamepad with Gyro" template only works in games that allow simultaneous gamepad and mouse input.